# HTTPS POST using cURL CLI to a NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl, https

I wrote an HTTPS NodeJS server (with a self signed certificate) where I want to receive and process POST requests from cURL CLI.

My server:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var config = require('./conf.json');
var g3updater_kernel = require('./g3updater_kernel');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync(config.security_repository+'/CA/rootCA.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync(config.security_repository+'/CA/rootCA.pem', 'utf8');

var httpsOptions = {
  key: privateKey,
  cert: certificate
}

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.query);
});


https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(443);
```

cURL command I use:

```
curl -d M=1 https://localhost/ -k
```

The problem is that I receive an empty query. `console.log(req.query)` displays:

```
{}
```

am I missing something in the query?

Comment: See if this article helps you [doing post on curl](http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to parse the queries in your post request you're going to want to use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).

In Express 4, there was conscious decision made to move bodyParser and CookieParser to separate modules.

In order to access your queries, you're code should look something like:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var config = require('./conf.json');
var g3updater_kernel = require('./g3updater_kernel');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync(config.security_repository+'/CA/rootCA.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync(config.security_repository+'/CA/rootCA.pem', 'utf8');

var httpsOptions = {
  key: privateKey,
  cert: certificate
}

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
});

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(443);
```

Note that they will be held in req.body instead of req.query.

Happy Coding!